# Identify bone found on beach in Scotland

Tags: species-identification, bone

Found on a beach in Scotland, it's about 10cm long, any ideas what it is?[image]

Comment: You should add the size too. it's a piece of skull. what's on the other side?

Comment: I cannot seem to add another picture but is is the same but 2 reccess on both sides. Is around 4 inches

Comment: It’s been suggested that it is A seal skull?

Comment: without scale this impossible to answer.

Comment: @karen you can upload 2-3 images, perhaps try a screenshot of thw image if the phone camera is too many mp for the site.